# iOS App crashes when I open multitask, 0x8badf00d exception

Tags: ios, crash, multitasking, watchdog

I have a problem in my app. Some our users are running into a crash where the system is terminating the app, it happens when they open multitask. I checked log files from test device, there were 2 types of logs.

1. appName.ips.beta
2. stacks+appName.ips

The first type contains enough info, I symbolicated log info and fixed the mistake.

But second type file does not contain "Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread ..." info. So I don't know how to understand it.

I found this info from logs.

> "exception" : "0x8badf00d"

The exception code 0x8badf00d indicates that an application has been terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. The application took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events.

How to get more info from this type of log?

Thanks in advance!

[logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xjm9YHF4GfO7h-fd4ydsssOe1gjCN9iU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you're not finding the source of the problem, I'd suggest you edit your question to include the thread 0 stack trace. It might not always include the salient details (as [Identify the Reason the Watchdog Triggered](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/identifying_the_cause_of_common_crashes/addressing_watchdog_terminations#3561607) warns us), but often it will.

Answer (score 1):

As I gather that you have figured out, `0x8badf00d` (pronounced “ate bad food”) is thrown by the watchdog process, when one blocks the main thread for too long. Often this is triggered by something blocking during app launch, but it can occur anywhere you block the main thread. For example, if you have something slow going on, locking the UI in the process, users have a natural tendency to jump to the home screen, to make sure their phone is OK, and when they jump back to your app, if it is still blocking, the watchdog might bite you.

See [Understanding the Exception Types in a Crash Report](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/understanding_the_exception_types_in_a_crash_report) . Also see [Addressing Watchdog Terminations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/identifying_the_cause_of_common_crashes/addressing_watchdog_terminations). But, in short, always avoid blocking the main thread (e.g., with slow, synchronous tasks) by adopting asynchronous patterns. We cannot get more specific than that without seeing the code that’s blocking the main thread.

But in your crash report, focus on the stack trace for the main thread, thread 0, which is hopefully symbolicated, as that is likely blocked with some synchronous task, which causes the watchdog process to kill your app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I removed all codes from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, but still, it crashes. So there is no way to have any info from logs that are blocking main thread?

Comment: Look at the stack trace for thread 0, the main thread. When that's blocked, that's when the watchdog process can kill your app. The [Addressing Watchdog Terminations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/identifying_the_cause_of_common_crashes/addressing_watchdog_terminations) link gives some counsel, too. But `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` isn't the only place you could have problems. E.g. `viewDidLoad` of some view controller, or whatever. Anything on the main thread.

Comment: Could you please send me that line of log? it could be so helpfull